# Regex for the following expression

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

I m currently doing an android application. I am trying to write a regular expression to extract the following type of expression from a string.

The expression starts with square bracket which can be followed by any number of characters. It is followed by a closing square bracket. it is followed by a opening parenthesis followed by any number of characters followed by a closing bracket.

```
[any character](any character)
```

for eg.,

```
if you want to apply for admission [click 1 here](www.abc.gid/heyde/ hduef) 
starting in the year 2013.
```

I need to extract **`[click 1 here](www.abc.gid/heyde/ hduef)`** from the above

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: There is no "above code". Anyway, you can start [here in the Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: @Jerry : edited the question. Please take a look

Comment: So now it is `[]{}` instead of `[]()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\[.*?\]\{.*?\}` on your example which I tested out [here](http://rubular.com/r/bPXM5Upsjw).

This breaks into two smaller regex:

1. `\[.*?\]`, which is the square brackets with any chars inside.
2. `\{.*?\}`, which is the curly brackets with any chars inside.

Both of these are using a non-greedy `.*` inside the brackets.  This way if there is more then one match per line, it will not grab both as one match.

Comment: If a line contains same two patterns its consider as one
Example : view group inf [click 1 here](www.abc.gid/heyde/ hduef) o below [click 1 here](www.abc.gid/heyde/ hduef) bla bla bla

Comment: @SHANib updated the answer to be non greedy which should take care of that issue

Comment: @SHANib also, in this example you are back to using `()` instead of `{}`.  It seems like the question/regex keeps shifting as more conditions are added on.  Make sure when you ask questions to note all of these conditions at the beginning so the answers are more correct and helpful, and are answered quicker and more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks.. wil be more careful and concious b4 posting a question...  now i have clear idea.. i want to accept both () or {} on the second part ie [...]{...} or [.....](.....).. can u pls  guide me on this

Comment: @SHANib if you need both (after the `[]`) then you can just expand the 2nd bracket piece using an `OR` clause inside of a group.  Group together the two conditions to to ensure one of them happens after your square brackets.  [Like this](http://rubular.com/r/jsOImAHpqY): `\[.*?\]((\{.*?\})|(\(.*?\)))`

Answer (score 0):

Well, as long as you don't allow brackets within brackets it shouldn't be too hard:

```
\[[^]]+]\([^)]+\)
```

Use `+` if you expect at least one character inside the brackets, use `*` otherwise.

The expression is matching as follows:

`\[` - match opening square bracket

`[^]]+` - match everything that is not a closing square bracket

`]` - match the closing square bracket

`\(` - match the opening round bracket

`[^)]+` - match everything that is not a closing round bracket

`\)` - match the closing round bracket